# Ios Application structure

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I still a beginner in iOS Development and while building my first app I had the following doubt: 
which is considered a better development criteria, having too many views in the app or having less views with more complicated class codes so that these view can be dynamically used?
I really would love to get your feed back as in my first app i can either use 17 view (simple and strait forward) or reduce them to 6 (complicating the codes and using much less classes eventually).

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the project requirement that how many views will have. It may be a topic of debate. You should have necessary views and classes but not more and unnecessary view is good. Also, to reduces the view you should not complex your classes.

You should follow the OOP (Object oriented Programming). That means,your need to write your **methods/classes** ,so that it can be reused.